# box-shadow splitted among pages - css for print issue

Tags: css, printing, box-shadow, page-break-inside

I'm trying to print a web page I created.

I also created a style.css with specific rules for print.

I have some div boxes representig comments I need not to be split inside among pages.

I added this property:

> page-break-inside: avoid;

This worked for the the shape (the bubble is correctly not split inside), but the box-shadow is still split among pages.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXxtT.jpg)

How can I solve this issue?